# get number from solidity with ethers.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

Is it possible to get uint256 value from Solidity using ethers.js ?
I want to receive a number on frontend; an integer.
I try to call the state variable and receive thhis, but i can't convert it to nomber:

> ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value:
> Array(0)}__zone_symbol__state: true__zone_symbol__value:
> BigNumber {_hex: '0x01', _isBigNumber: true}Symbol(Symbol.species):
> (...)Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: There number which you are trying to access is a variable of a return value?

Comment: I solve it using async/await